# Dynamic Web scraping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the tables from the below dynamic webpage. I am using the below code to find the data in tables (they are under tag name tr). But I am getting empty list as output. Is there anything that I am missing here?

https://www.taipower.com.tw/tc/page.aspx?mid=206&cid=406&cchk=b6134cc6-838c-4bb9-b77a-0b0094afd49d

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\upko\Downloads\My Projects\Ibrahim Projects\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.taipower.com.tw/tc/page.aspx?mid=206&cid=406&cchk=b6134cc6-838c-4bb9-b77a-0b0094afd49d")
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
```

[image: Please find the inspect code of webpage screenshot below]

Answer (score 1):

Website have iframes, you need switch into desired iframe to access data. Didnt tested code, but should work

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='IframeId']")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

#Now you can get data
trs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *visibility_of_all_elements_located*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.taipower.com.tw/tc/page.aspx?mid=206&cid=406&cchk=b6134cc6-838c-4bb9-b77a-0b0094afd49d")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//iframe[@id='IframeId']")))
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='container-fluid']//div[@class='span6']/strong")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['核能(Nuclear)', '燃煤(Coal)', '汽電共生(Co-Gen)', '民營電廠-燃煤(IPP-Coal)', '燃氣(LNG)', '民營電廠-燃氣(IPP-LNG)', ' 燃油(Oil)', '輕油(Diesel)', '水力(Hydro)', '風力(Wind)', '太陽能(Solar)', '抽蓄發電(Pumping Gen)']
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. I wanted to get the data in the tables inside the "tbody" and I tried giving the Xpath (instead of span6 in your code, I gave row and added /tr at the end instead of /strong), but I am getting timeout error.